# How can I merge cells horizontally respecting newlines in Google Sheets (or Excel)?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

In a spreadsheet I need to merge contents within the cells in an ABAB form where the newlines within each cell are respected. I need to do this for 1000s of lines so need an easy bulk procedure.

I need to maintain the current rows since later the CSV will be used for batch substitution into a subtitles files - 1 current row at a time. One row much continue to contain all the data relevant to one subtitle text string. However, I need to get the middle and left column contents combined from:

```
--cell one--     --cell two--

A1                  B1

A2                  B2

A3                  B3

--cell three--     --cell four--

C1                  D1

C2                  D2

C3                  D3
```

Into a desired result form of:

```
--cell one--     

A1(B1)

A2(B2)

A3(B3)

--cell three--     

C1(D1)..... etc....
```

So in other words all this in ONE CELL:

```
niemniej (still)
jednak (but)
zgodził (he agreed)
się udzielić (to grant)
Kate (kate)
wywiadu. (interview)
```

[google sheets translation word for word - SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13HNS.png)

Comment: VBA: use `Split(cellText, vbLf)` to create arrays from each of the two cells to be joined.  "zip" the two arrays together by looping over them and concatenating the text, then merge the cells and replace the text with the "zipped" version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(CHAR(10),SPLIT(B12,CHAR(10))&"("&SPLIT(C12,CHAR(10))&")"))
```

For Google sheets. For joining B12&C12

Comment: incredibly simple, i spent so much time looking in the wrong places for an approach! thanks

Answer (score 1):

It requires some helper columns, but here's a solution without VBA. This requires your data to start in cell A1 and also requires each line within each cell to be unique. It also requires Excel 2016 or later to use CONCAT function.

Array formula for cell C1 (must be saved using `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`):

`=LEFT(CONCAT(OFFSET(D1,0,0,1,MATCH(TRUE,ISERROR(D1:W1),0)-1)),LEN(CONCAT(OFFSET(D1,0,0,1,MATCH(TRUE,ISERROR(D1:W1),0)-1)))-1)`

Formula for cell D1:

`=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(10),A1)-1)`

Formula for cell E1:

`="("&LEFT(B1,FIND(CHAR(10),B1)-1)&")"&CHAR(10)`

Formula for cell F1:

`=IFERROR(MID($A1,FIND(D1,$A1)+LEN(D1)+1,FIND(CHAR(10),$A1,FIND(D1,$A1)+LEN(D1)+1)-(FIND(D1,$A1)+LEN(D1)+1)),RIGHT($A1,LEN($A1)-(FIND(D1,$A1)+LEN(D1))))`

Formula for cell G1:

`="("&IFERROR(MID($B1,FIND(MID(E1,2,LEN(E1)-3),$B1)+LEN(MID(E1,2,LEN(E1)-3))+1,FIND(CHAR(10),$B1,FIND(MID(E1,2,LEN(E1)-3),$B1)+LEN(MID(E1,2,LEN(E1)-3))+1)-(FIND(MID(E1,2,LEN(E1)-3),$B1)+LEN(MID(E1,2,LEN(E1)-3))+1)),RIGHT($B1,LEN($B1)-(FIND(MID(E1,2,LEN(E1)-3),$B1)+LEN(MID(E1,2,LEN(E1)-3)))))&")"&CHAR(10)`

Select both cells F1:G1, then use the fill handle to drag both formulas to cell W1

This will handle up to 10 lines per cell. If you need to handle more, drag the helper formulas past W1 as far as is required and update the reference to W1 in the formula in cell C1 to where you dragged the helper formulas. (Remember to save using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER every time you edit the array formula in cell C1.)

The result is displayed in cell C1. You need to manually change the text formatting of cell C1 to Wrap Text to see the newlines that were inserted.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to split the string with delimiter as newline (chr(13)) for both the columns

Then I concatenated values corresponding in each array

```
Sub splitandconcatenate()
Dim s1() As String, l1() As String
Dim rowcount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim lookupRowValue As String, sourceRowvalue As String
Dim sourceCol  As Integer, CheckCol As Integer

sourceCol = 1 ' 1 denotes Column A. Data in A column
CheckCol = 2 ' 2 denotes Column B. Data in B column
TargetCol = 3# ' 3 output is written in column c
rowcount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row 'counts the rows with data

'For each row
For currentRow = 1 To rowcount
     sourceRowvalue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
     lookupRowValue = Cells(currentRow, CheckCol).Value
'Split each cell with delimiter being newline chr(13)
     s1 = Split(Chr(13) & sourceRowvalue, Chr(13))
     l1 = Split(Chr(13) & lookupRowValue, Chr(13))
'Two arrays are created for two columns. For each string in the array, concatenate the corresponding string in the other array
      For i = 1 To UBound(s1)
         Cells(currentRow, TargetCol).Value = Cells(currentRow, TargetCol).Value & Chr(13) & s1(i) & "(" & l1(i) & ")"

       Next
Next
End Sub
```